# IOS IAP: Buying same item multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store

Hello Developer Community,

please let me know what you would think is the best idea to solve the problem, that one item cannot be sold multiple times if it is non-consuming.

Background:
We have a product like dropbox.
You can buy packages with space e.g.:

Package 1: 100 MB
Package 2: 200 MB
Package 3: 300 MB

Every package is for 1 year valid.

3 month before the package ends, it should be possible for the customer to buy the same package for the next 365 days or in other words extend the bought package für one more year.

Example:
A user buys the package 100 MB on January 1st. On October 1st he can open the store inside the app and sees again the same 300 products:

Package 1: 100 MB
Package 2: 200 MB
Package 3: 300 MB

Problem:
It is non-consumable, so you can buy one item only once.
Should I now do some (dirty :-)) tricks like I put different product identifiers for the same thing but another year?

100MbFirstYear
200MbFirstYear
300MbFirstYear

100MbSecondYear
200MbSecondYear
300MbSecondYear

Questions:
1.) What is the best approach to do this?
2.) How should I name the product Ids?

Best regards
Fipsi

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use subscription IAP

> Subscriptions:: You can also provide access to content in your app on a time-limited basis – making the user purchase a subscription to continue to access your content. Some examples would be subscribing to an electronic magazine, or subscribing to unlock an extra feature in an app for a month.

Check this tutorials on how to use it 
[In-App Purchases: Non-Renewing Subscription Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial)

Comment: Good idea. But where in I-Tunes Connect  can I describe the time period for the validity of 1 year?

Comment: @fipsikato the period won't be added to iTunes, that is some thing you need to do yourself in code to get the expiration date either using UserDefaults (not secure) or third party like Parse, all steps are explained in the tutorial link

Comment: Last question from my side: How should I handle whether if a product will be prolonged (buy the same item twice) or recovered (e.g. on another phone)? I think every time, when the user buys the same item again, then it will be NOT a new purchase, right?

Comment: I think you should attach the purchase to the user not the device, i.e. if the user is registered, use his username or email.

Comment: Yes for sure. Let me make my question simpler. I have 1 product id as Non-renewable subscription in ITunes connect.
My product should have a validity of 1 year.
After 1 year it should be possible to buy the same product (identifier) again.
How can I differentiate between
- restore the product and
- after 12 month buy it again ? The product will be restored everytime again instead of a new purchase or?

Comment: I didn't try it before but i think iOS will be smart enough to detect it as you can not restore Non-renewable subscription after the expiration date, you can only restore it before the expiration date and this will not extend the expiration date. you can check this on a example with 1 day period and see what will happen

Comment: OK. Thank you. I got it now. non-renewing subscription means that everytime you buy the same item, it will  be a new purchase and I thought it will be tried everytime to recover the bought product. But this is only the cases with non-consumable products. Thanky you!

Comment: @fipsikato i'll be pleased if you marked the answer as correct answer